# Construct array with query / files mixed in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, file

I have to following query:

```
$thumbs = scandir("/var/www/example.com/web/images/orders/".$orderId); // Actually script to search image files

$orderDescription = array();
$queryResult = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(OD.line) AS line, OD.artName AS artName, P.name AS name, OD.productSize AS size, OD.quantity AS quantity, OD.price AS unitPrice FROM OrderDetail OD JOIN Additional A ON A.orderId=OD.orderId LEFT JOIN Product P ON P.id=OD.productId WHERE OD.orderid=".$orderId) or die('Error al buscar la descripción del pedido #'.$orderId.' en la Base de Datos\n'.mysql_error());;
while($orderDescriptionDb = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResult)){
 / Array construct /
}
```

$orderId is a php variable to identify an order. I want to consult the database and obtein the following array:

```
Array (
 [1] => Array (
  [id] => 714
  [line] => 1
  [name] => Carpetas
  [size] => Carta
  [quantity] => 28
  [unitPrice] => 25.60
  [linePrice] => 716.8
  [artName] => Array (
    [carpeta endrina fermin] => [1326_P107_65_388_17800_thumb.jpg]
  )
 )
 [2] => Array (
  [id] => 714
  [line] => 2
  [name] => Afiches
  [size] => 1/4 Pliego
  [quantity] => 3
  [unitPrice] => 15.00
  [linePrice] => 45
  [artName] => Array (
    [invitaciones] => [1333_P29_24_388_16319_thumb.jpg]
  )
 ) 
)
```

The complex are that [1326_P107_65_388_17800_thumb.jpg] and [1333_P29_24_388_16319_thumb.jpg] are images files stored in the following route:

```
/var/www/example.com/web/images/orders/714
```

Now, I have problems with this array because the images are repeated two times (For each subarray).

Comment: do you want them in one row as [invitaciones] => [1326_P107_65_388_17800_thumb.jpg,1333_P29_24_388_16319_thumb.jpg] ?

Comment: nothing to answer the question, but I just have to say it: start to use PDO or Mysqli! Makes me hurt everytime I see something like `mysql_query("...".$variable)`. That code should not even compile imho. See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function, so those parentheses do not serve any purpose.